# How to determine which probability distribution this distribution is closest to?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I have run a simulation and obtained a large number of values which I have used to plot a discrete probability distribution. How do I determine which probability  distribution this distribution is closest to? I originally thought it was a binomial distribution but was told I was incorrect.

Distribution image:

[image]

Comment: What is the nature of your dataset? Are the data points in your dataset whole numbers? What kinds of distributions have you learned about? Have you learned about MLEs? There are many possible probability distributions that can fit a dataset.

Comment: The data set is whole numbers. The data is obtained from a game which is run continuously with the numbers in the game being randomly selected from an unknown distribution. The only distributions I have researched are binomial, poisson and bernoulli. I was hoping to find a way to determine a method to find a distribution that fits.

Comment: Many discrete distributions contain parameters, and different parameters generate different probability distributions. For example, the binomial distribution is parameterized by $n$ and $p$ while the Poisson distribution is parameterized by its mean $\lambda$. You're essentially trying to identify the distribution **and** the parameter(s) which generate a distribution that reasonably approximates the discrete distribution you have. One of the most common methods for identifying such parameters is the MLE. Have you learned about this?

Comment: No I haven't. Unfortunately probability is outside my field and have limited knowledge on the subject

Answer (score 0):

I will illustrate how to fit a dataset with some distribution and then establish whether such a fit is reasonable.

Suppose we're given the following hypothetical grouped dataset: $$\text{Class}:0,1,3,8,9,11$$ $$\text{Observed Frequency}:4,5,4,3,1,1$$ If we seek to fit this grouped data with a $\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$ distribution we will need to use our dataset to estimate $\lambda$. It is well$-$known that the MLE for $\lambda$ is the sample mean $\frac{\sum xf_x}{\sum f_x}=\frac{61}{18}$. To see if this assumption is reasonable we can perform the hypothesis test $$H_0: \text{We're sampling from a Poisson}\Big(\frac{61}{18}\Big) \text{ distribution}$$ $$H_a: \text{We're not sampling from a Poisson}\Big(\frac{61}{18}\Big) \text{ distribution}$$ Assuming $H_0$ is true the expected frequency for the class $0$ is $$P(X=0)\cdot \sum f_x \approx 0.607$$ where $X\sim \text{Poisson}\Big(\frac{61}{18}\Big)$. Continuing in this manner we get a list of "expected counts" shown below: $$\text{Class}:0,1,3,8,9,11$$ $$\text{Expected Frequency}:0.607,2.059,3.940,0.262,0.099,0.010$$ The test statsitic for this hypothesis test is $\sum \frac{(O-E)^2}{E}\approx 158$ which possesses a chi$-$squared distribution having $5$ degrees of freedom. The $p-$value is $$P(\chi^2_5\geq 158)\approx 0$$ So we'll reject $H_0$ and try to find some other distribution to fit our dataset.